# Is there a way to generate Square-Like Wave using Time Series data in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am relatively new to Python and Matplotlib.   Is there a way generate a **"square-like"** wave using a Panda series (i.e., a Time Series)?

For example, the following values are in the series:

12, 34, 97, -4, -100, -9, 31, 87, -5, -2, 33, 13, 1

Obviously, if I plot this series, it's not going to appear as a square wave.

Is there a way to tell Python that if the value is greater than zero, then plot consistent horizontal line above zero (e.g., let's say plot the line at 1), and if the value is below zero, plot a horizontal line below zero (e.g., at -1)?

Since this is a time series, I don't expect for it to be a perfect square.

Comment: See [numpy.sign](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) as:

```
x=[12, 34, 97, -4, -100, -9, 31, 87, -5, -2, 33, 13, 1]
np.clip(x, a_min=-1, a_max=1)

array([ 1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1])
```

Or [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) :

```
s = pd.Series(x)
s = s.clip(lower=-1, upper=1)
```

If it has values between >=-1 to <=1 then use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
x = np.where(np.array(x)>0, 1, -1) # for series s = np.where(s>0, 1, -1)
```

---

```
print(s) 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3    -1
4    -1
5    -1
6     1
7     1
8    -1
9    -1
10    1
11    1
12    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am new to Python and am still learning about the different methods.